# Format text input value with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an input that needs to be formated as **xx.xx.xx-xxx.xx**

I have the below code but until now i manage to format it as **xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-x**

Were i am i doing wrong.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Code:

```
var $form = $( ".commerce-add-to-cart" );
                    var $input = $form.find(".form-item-field-extra-velden-tkm-0-field-national-reg-num-und-0-value input");

                    $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {


                        var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
                        if ( selection !== '' ) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
                            return;
                        }

                        var $this = $(this);
                        var input = $this.val();
                                input = input.replace(/[\W\s\._\-]+/g, '');

                        var split = 4;
                        var chunk = [];

                        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += split) {
                            split = ( i >= 2 && i <= 9 ) ? 2 : 2;
                            chunk.push( input.substr( i, split ) );
                        }

                        $this.val(function() {
                            return chunk.join("-").toUpperCase();
                        });
                });
```

Comment: try and change `return chunk.join("-").toUpperCase();` to `return chunk.join(".").toUpperCase();`

Comment: @NickParsons added but is only replacing dash with dor. Also i need a dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach to formating the string, it might not be the most optimal but it does the trick quite nicely.

```js
let inputString = '01234567890';
let splitIndex = 6;

function format (value) {
  let firstPart = splitString(value.substring(0, splitIndex), 2).join('.');
  let secondPart = splitString(value.substring(splitIndex), 3).join('.');
  
  return [firstPart, secondPart].join('-');
}

function splitString (str, n) {
  let arr = [];
  var len;

  for(let i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += n) {
    arr.push(str.substr(i, n))
  }

  return arr;
}

let formatedInput = format(inputString);

console.log(formatedInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replace. Each of your capture groups is represented as $x and you can do there your format.

```js
const inputString = '01234567890';

const formatted = inputString.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{2})/g, "$1.$2.$3-$4.$5");

console.log(formatted);
```